# Is there a rule that says we can add a comma to identify which noun a relative pronoun refers to?

Tags: commas

I remember there was a rule I read on a Wikipedia article that says we can add a comma to mark which noun our relative pronoun refers to.

> The desktop computer of the Darwin family, which is rich.
>
> The desktop computer of the Darwin family which is broken.

These are two examples I came up with.

The problem is I don't remember all the details about the rule and I can't find it anymore.

Comment: Syntactically, *both* examples are ambiguous. It's just that *pragmatically* we know that ***rich + family*** and ***broken + computer*** are more likely pairings than the alternatives. All the comma does is (with *reasonable* certainty) disambiguate whether we're singling out *one specific* rich family / broken computer from others that *might* have been relevant, or simply providing additional information about the only one involved in the context anyway.

Comment: I am starting to wonder if my memories are playing some tricks.

Comment: The written form is really just the best we can do in terms of representing "real" language use (which is *spoken*). If you feel confused, it might help you to try ***speaking the words out loud*** - with or without an (exaggerated, if necessary) pause at the point where you might or might not include the comma. That should clarify things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two sentences you give don't use a comma to show which noun the relative pronoun refers to. They change it between being a restrictive clause and a nonrestrictive clause.

The comma on the first example makes it a nonrestrictive clause, so it is read as providing additional information. Whatever noun is the antecedent of 'which', it is being described as rich.

The lack of comma on the second example makes it a restrictive clause, so it is read narrowing things down. If the Darwin family refers to a specific family, and that family has multiple desktop computers, it makes it clear that the sentence is referring to the one computer that is broken.

(Note that this "comma means nonrestrictive" rule is not absolute, and you will run into counterexamples; personally, it makes sense to me that it's a result of the comma indicating that the clause is nonessential. It is a parenthetical clause that is not needed to convey the *essential meaning* of the sentence. Therefore it cannot be necessary in order to understand what computer or family is being referred to. Therefore it cannot be restrictive. But that's just a personal mental explanation for it, as far as I know, and there are most likely counterexamples).

No, when there's an ambiguous antecedent, we have to try and work it out semantically. In the first case, because its nonrestrictive, we assume "the Darwin family" is referring to a single family. Maybe their name is Darwin, or maybe there are several families being discussed and one lives in Darwin. We assume that "the Darwin family" is the antecedent of the 'which' because a computer can't be rich.

In the second case, we have multiple possible meanings, and with that sentence on its own it's a genuinely ambiguous antecedent. Wider context may help. If we have reason to believe that there is only one Darwin family being considered, then "desktop computer" is the only thing that could be the antecedent of the 'which'. If we don't have that restriction, then "the Darwin family" could be the antecedent, because it could be referring to the idea of a "*broken family*".

You can usually work out ambiguous antecedents from semantics or context, but not always. When writing, you need to be aware of possible confusion. You can fix it by rephrasing, or sometimes by changing pronoun. For example, while 'which' here could refer to the family as a unit, or the computer, 'who' could be used to refer to the family as a collection of people. That won't help in the second example, though, unless you wanted to suggest that the individual members of the family were each individually broken, which is rather different than the idea of a "broken family".

I have not, personally, heard of a rule that uses commas to indicate the antecedent of a pronoun. I can't think of one that I might know implicitly, either.